# Pandas - group by column and transform the data to numpy array

Tags: python, pandas, pivot, grouping

Having the following data frame, group A have 4 samples, B 3 samples and C 1 sample:

```
  group   data_1   data_2
0     A        1        4
1     A        2        5
2     A        3        6
3     A        4        7
4     B        1        4
5     B        2        5
6     B        3        6
7     C        1        4
```

I would like to transform the data into numpy array, where each row is a group with all its samples and zero padding for groups that have fewer samples.

Resulting in an array like so:

```
[
   [[1,4],[2,5],[3,6],[4,7]], # this is A group 4 samples
   [[1,4],[2,5],[3,6],[0,0]], # this is B group 3 samples
   [[1,4],[0,0],[0,0],[0,0]], # this is C group 1 sample
]
```

Answer (score 20, accepted):

First is necessary add missing values - first solution with [`unstack`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.unstack.html) and [`stack`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.stack.html), counter Series is created by [`cumcount`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.cumcount.html).

Second solution use [`reindex`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.reindex.html) by `MultiIndex`.

Last use lambda function with `groupby`, convert to numpy array by [`values`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.values.html) and last to lists:

```
g = df.groupby('group').cumcount()
L = (df.set_index(['group',g])
       .unstack(fill_value=0)
       .stack().groupby(level=0)
       .apply(lambda x: x.values.tolist())
       .tolist())
print (L)

[[[1, 4], [2, 5], [3, 6], [4, 7]], 
 [[1, 4], [2, 5], [3, 6], [0, 0]], 
 [[1, 4], [0, 0], [0, 0], [0, 0]]]
```

Another solution:

```
g = df.groupby('group').cumcount()
mux = pd.MultiIndex.from_product([df['group'].unique(), g.unique()])
L = (df.set_index(['group',g])
       .reindex(mux, fill_value=0)
       .groupby(level=0)['data_1','data_2']
       .apply(lambda x: x.values.tolist())
       .tolist()
)
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply, but I get an error KeyError: "Columns not found: 'data_2', 'data_1'"

Comment: @ShlomiSchwartz - What is `print (df.columns.tolist())` ?

Comment: .stack().groupby(level=0)['data_1','data_2'] causes the error, before that line the df looks like so `       data_1           data_2         
            0  1  2  3       0  1  2  3
group                                  
A           1  2  3  4       4  5  6  7
B           1  2  3  0       4  5  6  0
C           1  0  0  0       4  0  0  0`

Comment: @ShlomiSchwartz - Just realised it is not necessary `['data_1','data_2']`

Comment: could you please have a look here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52735334/python-resample-dataset-to-have-balanced-classes ?

Comment: @ShlomiSchwartz - I check ed it, but unfortuantely I have no experiece with it :( So I upvote for highlight your question.

Comment: Hi, what should I change in the code if I don't want to fill values and would rather have a jagged nested list instead?

Comment: @SaketKumarSingh - Try remove `.reindex(mux, fill_value=0)`